# unicode method doesn't work in Python3

Tags: python

```
def unicode_csv_reader(utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

filename = '/Users/congminmin/Downloads/kg-temp.csv'
reader = unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))

out_filename = '/Users/congminmin/Downloads/kg-temp.out'
#writer = open(out_filename, "w", "utf-8")
for question, answer in reader:
  print(question+ " " + json.loads(answer)[0]['content'])
  #writer.write(question + " " + answer)

reader.close();
```

This code works in Python 2.7. But it gives an error message in Python 3.6:

```
Unresolved reference 'unicode'
```

How to adapt it to Python 3.6?

Comment: Python 3 has built in unicode support. `yield row` will work just fine.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you mean I can just do "yield [cell for cell in row]"?

Comment: You can, but that's the same as `yield row`, except you are making an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Show how you call your generator function.

Comment: Please see my addition.

Comment: I've posted an answer. In Python 3 you don't need any of the messy unicode stuff at all. It all happens magically under the hood.

Comment: Also, please don't change code in a question after you've received answers. Your whole question was about the `unicode` class, and now you've invalidated your own question.

Comment: I've gone ahead and reverted that part of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3 has excellent unicode support already. Any time you open a file in text mode, you can use a specific encoding, or let it default over to UTF-8. There is no longer a difference between `str` and `unicode` in Python 3. The latter does not exist, and the former has full unicode support. This simplifies your job greatly since you don't need your setup method at all. You can just iterate over a normal `csv.reader`.

As an additional note, you should always open files in a `with` block, so things get cleaned up if there is any kind of exception. As a bonus, your file will get closed automatically when the block ends:

```
with open(filename) as f:  # The default mode is 'rt', with utf-8 encoding
    for question, answer in csv.reader(f):
        # Do your thing here. Both question and answer are normal strings
```

This will only work properly if you are sure that each row contains exactly 2 elements. You may be better off doing something more like

```
with open(filename) as f:  # The default mode is 'rt', with utf-8 encoding
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if len(row) != 2:
            continue  # Or handle the anomaly by other means
        question, answer = row
        # Do your thing here as before
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply ensure your data is `str`, not a bytestring, to begin with, and just use `csv.reader` without this decoding stuff.

```
data = utf8_data.decode('utf-8')
for row in csv.reader(data, dialect=csv.excel, ...):
    # ...
```

Comment: My utf8_data is returned by the file open method.